# jQuery ONE function re-activates multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick

I have many `<div>` each containing another div that's my button. I have an `.one('click', '.button', function(){});` that activates on each click and increments a number in a single div elsewhere.

```
 var barPrimC = 25;
 var barPrimN = 6;
 var barPrimS = 5;
 var barPrimT = 48;

 var barSecMajC = 11;
 var barSecMajN = 2;
 var barSecMajS = 3;
 var barSecMajT = 19;

var incSL

$('.complete, .incomplete').click(function() {

    $('.classInfo').slideUp();

    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {

        $(this).addClass('on');

        $(this).next().show('slow');

        incSL = this;

        // ADD to List
        $(".shortAdd").one('click','.button', function(){

                $(this).text('Remove from Short List');

                $(this).parent().attr("class", "shortRemove");

                $(incSL).attr("class", "incompleteSL");

                $('.classInfo').slideUp();

                barPrimS++;
                barSecMajS++;

                var updateBarP = $(".bpS").find(".b-text-right").text(barPrimS);

                var cat = $(this).data("category");
                var catBar = $("."+cat).find(".bCommonS");
                var updateBarS = catBar.filter(".bsS").find(".s-text-right").text(barSecMajS);


        });

        // REMOVE from List
        $(".shortRemove").one('click','.button', function(){

                $(this).text('Add to Short List');

                $(this).parent().attr("class", "shortAdd");

                $(incSL).attr("class", "incomplete");

                $('.classInfo').slideUp();

                barPrimS--;
                barSecMajS--;

                var updateBarP = $(".bpS").find(".b-text-right").text(barPrimS);

                var cat = $(this).data("category");
                var catBar = $("."+cat).find(".bCommonS");
                var updateBarS = catBar.filter(".bsS").find(".s-text-right").text(barSecMajS);

        });

    }

 });
```

I was originally using `.on` but it was activating both of my methods *(for ADD and REMOVE clicks)*.

If I have :

```
<div>1st time div CLICKED (runs 1 time)</div>
<div>2nd time div CLICKED (runs 2 times)</div>
<div>3rd time div CLICKED (runs 3 times)</div>
<div>4th time div CLICKED (runs 4 times)</div>
```

So basically if barPrimS starts off at 5, it goes to 6 when the `add` click method is ran. When a separate `add` click method is ran, it goes to 8. Then to 11 then to 15.

I can't figure out why this is happening, please help! Should increment by only 1 (5, 6, 7, 8). I've tried `barPrimS = barPrimS + 1` and other ways, but they all do the same.

Comment: `.one` will get executed only once .. ***Suggestion***: **Never nest event**

Comment: I have many different *things*, let's say, the user can *add* and so I need to be able to dynamically change part of the page as well as change the state of the original button clicked. This allows them to click the original button to change the state back. And each consecutive div will also have it's own state.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the `.shortAdd` and `.shortRemove` `.on('click')` methods from within the parent click even, as suggested, and didn't nest them. I then combined the short and add as an `if/else` statement under the `.shortAdd` and simply `.toggleClass()` with the `.shortRemove` class, checking to see if it existed.

This fixed all errors for me.